# AWS LB Health checks failed with these codes 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I deploy a application using github action from there its deploy to AWS Amazon Elastic Container Service as fargate. Application is running but its fail at health check(target register) reason i dont know i try to troubleshoot but its live application i doesnt want to break anything from my side but application is API or application is breaking down as developer complaining to me. I want to fix that unhealth issue why its not correctly configuring

Here is the github action job build logs

```
"message": "(service web-xxx-xxx-service) (port 8080) is unhealthy in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-1:***:targetgroup/web-app-api-tg/b3e0xxxxx753d) due to (reason Health checks failed with these codes: [404])."
message": "(service web-xxx-xxx-service) (deployment ecs-svc/5676780xxxxxx96392) deployment failed: tasks failed to start."
```

Registered targets are getting failed here is the screenshot

[image: Registered targets]

Here is the task:
[image: Task]

Here is the logs
[image: logs]

Here is the health check
[image: health check]

Here is the configuration
[image: configuration]

Here is the resource usage 1 vCPU 3 GB:
[image: resource usage]

Here is the attributes of task group:
[image: attributes of task group]

Port is listening to

```
HTTP:80 HTTP:8080 HTTPS:443
```

I made some changes in Health check settings like increase Interval from 30 to 100 and also i'm not using of changing Path from /api/v1/ping to / will work or not dont know and also i manual deploy target register in different zone like target register in 2 different zone but got all fail to connect.